# struts2 input iteration

Tags: forms, struts2, freemarker, textinput

Im using struts2 with freemarker template and i want to iterate over inputs and save them in search criteria.

In my action i have

```
private SearchCriteria criteria.
```

with method setCriteria and get criteria

```
public void setCriteria(SearchCriteria criteria) {
  this.criteria= criteria;
}
public SearchCriteria getCriteria() {
    return criteria;
}
```

In the criteria I can set list of objects ProductToSearch, with lets say id and label inside.

In my ftl file im iterating over the list of produtctsToSearch

```
<input id="test1" type="text" name="criteria.produtctToSearch[0].id" value="123" />
<input id="test2" type="text" name="criteria.produtctToSearch[0].label" value="testLabel" />
<input id="test1" type="text" name="criteria.produtctToSearch[1].id" value="123" />
<input id="test2" type="text" name="criteria.produtctToSearch[1].label" value="testLabel" />
```

but after looking at my criteria object, list of productsToSearch inside is empty.

Im calling my action via ajax with data: `$("#form").serialize();`
serialized values are:

```
criteria.produtctToSearch%5B1%5D.id=123&criteria.produtctToSearch%5B1%5D.label=testLabel&...
```

Can you tell me what am i missing?

Comment: Don't know yet; is that a typo in your template? Is there a public setter for the list? Need details.

Comment: That the template snippet is 100% static text BTW. I mean, it can't contain FreeMarker errors.

Comment: the question and the code that i use in example is not a real code, i just wrote it to explain the problem i am facing.

Comment: Do you see any exceptions in logs?